# Proving properties of $\exp(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I have already proven the following property (taken from Baby Rudin Chapter 5 Exercise 26), which I think is supposed to help me in some way:

> If $f$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$, $f(a) = 0$, and there is a real
>   number $A$ such that $|f^\prime x)| \leq A|f(x)|$ on $[a, b]$, then
>   $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,  b]$.

I am trying to prove the following properties about the exponential function $\exp : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ using the definition
$$
[\exp(x)]^\prime = \exp(x) \\
\exp(0) = 1.
$$

(I'll provide some brief sketches of ideas I have, and I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out the flaws in my reasoning or provide some suggestions to create better arguments.)

> 1. $\exp(x) > 0$ and $\exp(x)$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$.

It seems that we can proceed by showing that $\exp(x)$ can never change sign. If it did, i.e. $\exp(a) = 0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then, since we have 
$$
|[\exp(x)]^\prime| = |\exp(x)| \leq A |\exp(x)|,
$$ 
we would have that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, \infty]$. However, I'm not sure what to do about the case where $a > 0$ because then it doesn't contradict $\exp(0) = 1$.

In any case, after showing that $\exp(x) > 0$, we then get $[\exp(x)]^\prime > 0$ for free, which shows that $\exp$ is strictly increasing by Rudin Theorem 5.11.

> 2. $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

I took the derivative of
$$
f(x) = \exp(x+y) - \exp(x)\exp(y),
$$
using properties of derivatives listed in Rudin:
$$
\begin{align*}
f^\prime (x) &= [\exp(x+y) - \exp(x)\exp(y)]^\prime \\
&= [\exp(x+y)]^\prime - [\exp(x)\exp(y)]^\prime \\
&= \exp(x+y) - \exp(y)[\exp(x)]^\prime \\
&= \exp(x+y) - \exp(x)\exp(y)
\end{align*}
$$

This again means that $|f^\prime (x)| \leq A|f(x)|$, and clearly $f(0) = 0$, so by the exercise we have that $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$ for all $x \in [0, \infty]$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Perhaps we could repeat the argument in terms of $y$ to get the $x \in \mathbb{R}$ part?

> 3. $\exp(-x) = \frac{1}{\exp(x)}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

From (2), 
$$
\exp(0) = 1 = \exp(x - x) = \exp(x)\exp(-x),
$$
and the desired result follows.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Are there any errors in my solutions? Are there better ways of going about proving these things?

Comment: With regards to better ways, I am certain these have been proven on the site in detail many times. You can search for those solutions.

Comment: With regards to errors, I don't notice any myself; it seems that you know what you are doing. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what you were actually asking. You may get a better response if you are explicit at the beginning of the question about what you need.

Comment: I've added the "proof verification" tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm sorry --- I couldn't quite find a question on the site that asked precisely what I was asking for. I will also be more explicit in the future.

Comment: No worries, I am just providing feedback, and working to clarify the question for others who might share my confusion.

Comment: The accepted answer on this question might help you with property (1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785804/how-to-show-that-if-fxy-fxfy-then-fx-geq-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1). If $g'=g$ and $g(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$ then $g(x)=0$ for all $x.$

Proof: Case 1.If  $[-1/2+x,1/2+x]\subset g^{-1}\{0\}$ for all $x\in g^{-1}\{0\}$ then $\Bbb R=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}[-n/2+x_0,n/2+x_0]\subset g^{-1}\{0\}.$

(ii). Case 2. Suppose $g(x)=0$ and $|y-x|\le 1/2$ and $g(y)\ne 0.$ Then since $g$ is continuous  there exists $z$ with $|z-x|\le |y-x|$ and $g(z)=g(y)$ and such that $|g(w)|\le|g(y)|$ for all $w$ between $x$ and $z.$ Now  $g'$ is continuous (as it is equal to the differentiable, hence continuous, $g$) so $$0\ne |g(z)|=|g(z)-g(x)|=|\int_x^zg'(w)dw\;|=$$ $$=|\int_x^z g(w)dw\;|\le$$ $$\le |\int_x^z|g(w)|dw\;|\le $$ $$\le |\int_x^z |g(z)|dw\;|=$$ $$=|z-x|\cdot |g(z)|\le |g(z)|/2$$ which is absurd.

(2). If $f'=f$ and $f(0)=1$ then $f$ is strictly increasing and positive.

Proof: By (1) we cannot have $f(x)=0$ for any $x.$ And if $f(x)<0$ for some $x,$ then since  $f$ is continuous and $f(0)>0,$ there would be some $y$ between $x$ and $0$ with $f(y)=0.$ So $f$ is positive. Now since $f' (=f)$ is positive, $f$ is strictly increasing

(3). With $f$ as in (2), for any $y$ let $g_y(x)=f(x)f(y)-f(x+y).$ Then $\frac {dg_y(x)}{dx}=g_y(x)$ and $g_y(0)=0.$ By (1), $g_y(x)=0$ for all $x.$ This holds for any $y,$ so $f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)=0$ for all $x,y.$

(4). It remains to show that there $does$ exist $f$ with $f'=f$ and $f(0)=1.$